# How to convert proc mixed from SAS to R- unstructured covariance

Tags: r, sas, lme4

I'm trying to convert the following syntax from SAS to R (lmer).

```
CLASS  obs_id dyad gender_class; 
MODEL pep_1_00 = male female male*pep_lag_1 female*pep_lag_1 male*pep_lag_2 female*pep_lag_2
/NOINT CL S DDFM=SATTERTH ;
RANDOM male female male*pep_lag_1 female*pep_lag_1 /SUB=dyad TYPE=un;
RANDOM male*pep_lag_2 female*pep_lag_2 /SUB=dyad TYPE=vc;
REPEATED gender_class /SUB=dyad*obs_id TYPE=csh; 
RUN;
```

I have some difficulties with adjusting the code to lmer:

1. The line in the code that specifies an unstructured covariance `TYPE=un`- from what I understand the meaning of this is we ask the model to estimate the covariance between all the random effects in this line (male, female, male* pep_lag_1, female* pep_lag_1), how do we write this in R?
2. `TYPE=csh`- enable the degree of unexplained variance for dyad members to be different. How to specifies it in R?

This is the syntax I wrote in R (I know it's incomplete):

```
model_1 <- lmer(pep_1_00  ~ male + female + male*pep_lag_1 + female*pep_lag_1 + male*pep_lag_2 + female*pep_lag_2
                            +(male + female + male*pep_lag_1 + female*pep_lag_1 | dyad) 
                            +(male*pep_lag_2 + female*pep_lag_2 || dyad)
                            , Data_Ex1)
```

A little background- the data is repeated measures of members in dyads (male-female dyads). The outcome variable is a physiological response in time t, and the fixed and random effects are the participant's physiological response in time t-1 (pep_lag_1) and the other member in the dyad physiological response in time t-1 (pep_lag_2), which is defined separately for male and female:

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.